# Remote validation in mvc3 for file upload httppostedfilebase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my model

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Remote("FileSize", "Validation")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload1 { get; set; } 

}
```

## validation controller

```
 public JsonResult FileSize(HttpPostedFileBase value)
    {   
        return Json("File size is too big", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

My problem is i am not getting the value , always getting the null value

Comment: can you use jquery to check file size??...@KanakarajThangavel..

Comment: Your 'value' must match the name in the `<input name="<name>" />`

Answer (score 0):

just use object as parameter
so it will change as
(HttpPostedFileBase value )----REPLACE WITH--->
(Object  FileUpload1 )